# Instance from two other classes

Tags: vb.net

There are two classes, ClassA and ClassB and a third class ClassG.
Is it possible to do

```
Dim c as new ClassG()
```

and depending on a variable, say x, c will be an instantiation of ClassA or ClassB?

I could do:

```
    Dim c as Object
If x = true then
    c = new ClassA
Else
    c = new ClassB
End If
```

but, is there a better way? How?

Comment: You have to specify the type of the variable. If you intend to assign objects of different types to the variable, it must be a base type common to all of those. If the only common base type is object, that is your only option. If all the other types inherit the same base class, e.g. `Button` and `TextBox` both inherit `Control`, then you can declare the variable as that type. Another option is to declare the variable as a common interface, e.g. `IEnumerable` for various collection types.